# How to get the value of all the select option and input type from a row of table

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table and each row contains some columns as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="level1 selectLevel">
                <option value="0">Provincia</option>
                <option value="62">Aguascalientes</option>
                <option value="73">Baja California Norte</option>></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="level1 selectLevel">
                <option value="0">Provincia</option>
                <option value="62">Aguascalientes</option>
                <option value="73">Baja California Norte</option>></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="level4" /><button  class="add" type="button" >+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="level1 selectLevel">
                <option value="0">Provincia</option>
                <option value="62">Aguascalientes</option>
                <option value="73">Baja California Norte</option>></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="level1 selectLevel">
                <option value="0">Provincia</option>
                <option value="62">Aguascalientes</option>
                <option value="73">Baja California Norte</option>></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="level4" /><button  class="add" type="button" >+</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get the values of all the select options and input texts of each row when I click on (+) button ,

Some script that I am trying is as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', ".add", function(){
        var val = $(this).closest("input").val();
        alert(val);

    });
```

I have created a Fiddle for this [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ffxsuju8/)

It would be really helpful if some one can give me some idea

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ffxsuju8/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        var firstSelect = $(this).closest('tr').find('.first').find('select').val();
        var secondSelect = $(this).closest('tr').find('.second').find('select').val();
        var input = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        alert('first select value = '+ firstSelect + ', second select = ' + secondSelect + ', input value = ' + input);
    });
});
```

In order to do this, i added class first and second on the td elements for the select values

```
    <td class="first">
        <select class="level1 selectLevel">
            <option value="0">Provincia</option>
            <option value="62">Aguascalientes</option>
            <option value="73">Baja California Norte</option>></select>
    </td>
    <td class="second">
        <select class="level1 selectLevel">
            <option value="0">Provincia</option>
            <option value="62">Aguascalientes</option>
            <option value="73">Baja California Norte</option>></select>
    </td>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks bro this what I want actually have to do ajax call by sending these select values to save in a DB , You made my work really easy thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
    var values = $(this).closest('tr').find('option:selected, input[type="text"]').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffxsuju8/4/)

Comment: This is nice and simple, but its getting the select value of the last column that I do not want ,

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', ".add", function () {
    var val = $(".selectLevel",$(this).parents("tr")).eq(0).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

explanation:

- $(*`<what>`*,*`<where>`*) - jQuery selector format, we search for `".selectLevel"` within `$(this).parents("tr")`
- `$(this).parents("tr")` - searches the parent `tr` nodes of the current element. there will be only one in our case.
- `.eq(0)` - since we get a list of 2 select node,s this will give us the first one in the returned list.

<kbd>**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffxsuju8/2/)**</kbd>